# Nmap: Scanning Android Smart Phone But All Ports Always Filtered/Closed?

Tags: android, nmap, port-scanning

I am using Nmap and scanning my smart phone on my local network. I'm practicing trying to gain access into my smart phone (LG G5 - Android). However, whenever I scan my cell phone either all ports are closed or filtered, but the "host is up." I've tried SYN scans, ACK scans, TCP scans, all using fragmented packets, spoofed MAC address, stealthy speeds, etc. But either the cell phone simply blocks my attempts, time-outs, or returns all ports as either closed or filtered.

My questions are this:

1. **Is there any reason why my cell phone would be filtering all ports by default? (i.e., is a cell phone doing something different than my Apple or Windows computers?)**
2. **Any recommendations for being able to scan my cell phone and see what ports are actually open/closed?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question isn't very programming related.  Using a shell on your android device will list everything open.  The reason your device is `up` is because it's responding to `ICMP` packets while all of the `filtered` packets are on `tcp` or `udp`.  It's unlikely that a stock android device will be listening and there it is likely that all ports will appear to be filtered.

Comment: @Colton thanks you are right, this question should probably be over on security.stackexchange. But thanks for the information none the less.

Answer (score 0):

All ports are closed or filtered when scanning an android phone using nmap, it is because even if your phone is connected to your local network android devices have firewall which prevents you from knowing the status of ports(i.e., it is closed or open?). So don't worry, it is due to just firewall which blocks you from scanning and it can be bypassed with advanced exploitation.

For that, first you can practice with virtual vulnerable machines(i.e., Metasploitable)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, try these:

- IPPROTO scan -sO
- UDPscan -sU
  these techniques worked for me.